# Getting user input

Tags: sql-server

I try to get user input but I get an error and I'm not sure what to do,as I'm new into databases and according to w3schools this is the way to do it.

```
vers = getRequestString("Give the version you want:");
```

I get `Incorrect syntax near 'vers'.`
What am I missing?

Comment: The SQL Server *engine* has no means to request user input. This needs to be done by your application/query tool. (Your application might be SQL Server Reporting Services for example or something that you programmed yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Like Martin stated above, SQL Server cannot accept input or parameters directly from users.  Normally you would have an application collect the data and then pass it to the database.

Can you provide more information about how the input is being collected from the user?

Mark